# bypass data limit

Tags: network, vpn, internet

So as security student, I have been tasked with the challenge of trying to figure out a way of bypassing an ISPs data limit of 1GB . When the 1GB ceiling is hit the internet becomes really slow

I have tried to use a VPN but this method did not work.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: Sending traffic via VPN is still sending traffic. Just because the ISP can't see encrypted packets doesn't mean they won't count.

Comment: I have corrected the grammar, spelling & punctuation for you (currently awaiting peer review) however, you need to better explain what you're trying to do specifically `. After researching I found a method that requires a free site which the ISP doesn't have.` what do you mean by `a site the ISP doesn't have`? Please edit your question as it stands this is too broad & honestly difficult to answer based on your description of the task at hand.

Comment: I guess by _free site_ OP means sites that the ISP allows connecting but does not charge for traffic, like the Free Wikipedia Project (something like that).

Comment: How about DNS tunneling?

Comment: You can embed VPN into port 53 udp traffic, and it is mostly open. However, your ISP may detect it as DNS DOS attack, and they won't thank it to you.

Comment: Out of curiosity, has anyone here tried the method @peterh described?

Comment: @DavidB I tried it, two days later my outgoing UDP started to have around >80% packet loss, except if I turned the VPN off. I found it better if I don't ask my ISP what is happened. It was an OpenVPN simply configured to udp:53, there was no further tries to make it more DNS looking. Btw, my goal was not to bypass their data limit, but to bypass their general low data limit on *any* UDP traffic (yes, that we can call a psycho ISP). As I estimated, yes they had an exception on port53 - for a while.

Comment: @peterh Interesting. My plan has an actual cap that once I exceed, I am entirely cut off. I conserve my data to avoid reaching the cap, but I wonder if this would let me get around it. Even if it's slow, it's still better than nothing.

Comment: @DavidB It might work, try it! Do an `echo test|nc -u your.remote.server.ip:53` and check with a `tcpdump` on the remote side, if the packet arrives. If not, then check with a `host` command if any DNS answer arrives.

Comment: @peterh Wouldn't I have to reach my cap before testing this though? Presumably I would not have any issues with passing data through UDP 53 before reaching my cap.

Comment: @DavidB What is "cap" in this context?

Comment: @peterh In this context, "cap" means that every time I try to do something through my LTE connection, I get a landing page that says something like "Your bandwidth limit has been reached."

Comment: @DavidB Package it into https traffic, the ISP has no way to differentiate it from ordinary communication. You can pack even VPN into that. What if you simply start an openvpn on :443? It will be visible that it is not https, but such a deep inspection is imho unlikely (and, you can also embed openvpn into httptunnel, so it will be encrypted communication over ordinary http).

Comment: @peterh I actually run one of my OpenVPN server on TCP 443, and while I have not tried using it to bypass my cap, I have tried using it many times on paywalled WiFi, and it has not worked, so I would expect that it also would not work here. As for httptunnel, that is an interesting solution, but one that I am not familiar with. I will have to research it.

Comment: @peterh I had access to a paywalled WiFi hotspot for the first time today since I set up my VPN server on UDP 53, and I was able to connect! The problem is that the connection was really slow. I am not sure if this was a side effect of using the DNS port or if I was too far from the hotspot.

Answer (score 2):

a usual way that comes to my mind is abuse "white listed" services.   like ispyouron.com   something.affiliate-of-yourisp.com  as they usually do not count data to there own services, if you can find a proxy server or socks thats considered in those domains you would be set.

Comment: What do you mean considered?